# Can we use as.is with a vector?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a character vector say

```
a <- c('a','b','c','d')
```

The output for the vector is

```
"a","b","c","d","e"
```

`as.is` instruction elects us to read any column as plain text. This works for `data.frame`. Can I use as.is for vector?

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to accomplish...AFAIK `as.is` simply turns off the automatic conversion of text columns to factors in `read.table` function...

Comment: The `a`-symbol is assigned a "plain-text" type, but it is more accurately called `character`. Agree with digEmAll that it's not clear what you are attempting.